# how to get correct physical memory and virtual memory

Tags: visual-c++

I use this windows API,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx
GlobalMemoryStatusEx to get memory information 
my computer total physcial memory is 4096MB ,why the program shows 3.XG
My computer's virtual memory is 3063MB ,but i use program which show 2047MB
my develop enviroment is visual studio 2008
how to modify this problem

thanks

Comment: What OS are you running?  32-bit versions of Windows can't address the full 4GB of RAM because other things need to be available in the address space too.  See http://members.cox.net/slatteryt/RAM.html

Comment: my os is windows 7 32 bit but using cpu-z can get4GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Aren't other programs using your system as well?  I suspect the memory you're "missing" is due to the OS itself and whatever other programs you're running.  See if having a bunch of other applications open changes the virtual memory size that your program is able to see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running a 32bit version of windows, then this is a limit of windows itself.  See this Microsoft page for the [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  By default you will only be able to access 2GB of RAM in a single process.  There is a compiler switch in visual studio which will give you access to 3GB.  This is the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE switch.  Beyond that you just need to upgrade to a 64bit operating system.

By the way, the basic reason why you don't automatically get 4GB of address space is because part of it is reserved for the operating system.  Those system calls and references to operating system resources have to live somewhere.